# SQLCMD to import large sql file gives "Invalid object name" error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd, ssms-2012

I am trying to import a large .SQL file ([downloaded here](http://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm)) (210mb) containing postcodes in a table called `postcodelatlng`. This is the setup:
[image]

I tried executing the query directly in SSMS 2012 but it's complains about the lack of memory.

Further reading, pointed me use command tools using `SQLCMD`, where I tried:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -S (LocalDB)\v11.0 -i D:\Ben\Desktop\ukpostcodesmssql_1.sql
```

But this throws me this error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server BEN-PC\LOCALDB#850F4379, Line 1  Invalid object name 'postcodelatlng'.
```

Which I guess it's just not reaching that table correctly. I'm sure it's probably a rookie mistake but I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Do you have access to the Import/Export Wizard? SSIS?

Comment: @JiggsJedi yes I have access to the Import/Export wjzard. Not sure what SSIS is but I'll get back to you on that one

Comment: Both can load large data files no problem.  The Import/Export Wizard is your best bet if you aren't familiar with SSIS.  This would be used to load the CSV (raw data), not the .SQL (command) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .SQL file is plain text.  Open it using a text editor (I recommend NotePad++) and then copy & paste the commands into SSMS partially and execute incrementally until you have all of the records loaded.

Comment: I did actually find a way to split the [SQL file directly](http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/) (rather than copy and paste). But there has to be a better way than having to manually copy&paste / import 50 smaller files....

Comment: Use the `Go To` command to grab a batch of `INSERTs`.  In NotePad++ you can find it under the `Search` menu

Comment: I would think the "better" way is loading the actual data instead of using the script, but I thought you had a reason for using the .SQL instead of the .CSV.

Comment: I actually downloaded the file a few months ago (with the url) and never checked to see if there was a CSV file! Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to specifcy the database name? (-d db_name). Your command only looks to specify the server and sql script file.

Comment: I've just tried specifying the db name: `C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -S (LocalDB)\v11.0 -d postcodelatlng -i D:\Ben\Deskto
p\ukpostcodesmssql_1.sql` which gives me this  
`Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login failed for user '
Ben-PC\Ben'..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Cannot open database "p
ostcodelatlng" requested by the login. The login failed.`

The PC doesn't have a password, but I'll try look at the credentials flags and see if that unblocks it